# Formalizing graph theory proof that for every even number $n \geq 4$ there exists a graph with $n$ vertices, all of which have degree 3

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I just started self-studying *Pearls in Graph Theory* by Hartsfield and Ringel today. I am recent grad with a Bachelors in applied math, and don't have extensive proof experience. I've spent the past hour or so trying to formulate a proof (anything that makes sense is better than nothing, so my thoughts/methods are not so rigorous) for the below problem, but would like some guidance or an explanation for a better way to go about the proof.

> Prove that for every even number $n \geq 4$ there exists a graph with $n$ vertices, all of which have degree 3, without using Theorem 1.1.2 (Havel-Hakimi algorithm).

I've checked out these two questions:
- [Show that for every even number $n \geq 4$ there is a 3 regular graph with $n$ vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824806/show-that-for-every-even-number-n-4-there-is-a-3-regular-graph-with-n-vertice)
- [Prove that for every $n \geq 4$ there exists a planar, connected, and 3-regular graph with $n$ vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595890/prove-that-for-every-even-n-ge-4-there-exists-a-planar-connected-and-3-regu)

This question is in section 1.1, and we have not been introduced to the terms "connected" or "regular" yet (although I know "connected" from courses in college), so I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using other techniques? (Or a proof that includes formality with a visual proof.)

For reference, the only other theorem in section 1.1 is the one stating that $$\sum_{v \in V} deg (v) = 2|E|,$$ along with a bunch of basic definitions.

I am realizing now that my reasoning (after this paragraph) is focusing on a special case where every set of four or six vertices forms a subgraph and that all these subgraphs together combine to form the whole graph of $n$ vertices. I'm wondering if there is any way to use these thoughts in a proof or what a different–obviously more formal and general–way (i.e. every subgraph is attached to the whole graph) to think of this could be.

My thoughts:
 - $n \geq 4$ is even $\Rightarrow n = 4 + 2k, k \in \mathbb{N_0}$
 - If $k$ is even, then $n = 4(r+1)$, $r\geq 0$ and we can have $r+1$ subgraphs of four vertices with three edges each, as below:
   [image: four-vertex graph, each vertex has three edges]
 - If $k$ is odd, then $n = 4 + 2(2r-1) = 4(r+1)-2 = 4(r-1) + 6$, $r \geq 1$. We can have $r-1$ graphs of the four vertex graph, and one graph of six vertices where each vertex has 3 edges, like below:
  [image: six-vertex graph, each vertex has three edges]

After thinking it through and writing all of this out, I see that my work is quite similar to the visual proof (by user Aqua) in the second linked question above. How might I go about using my thoughts (if they're reasonable) and that proof to make a general, formal proof for this problem?

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't initially think of that when I was brainstorming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks OK.

You can write a formal proof the following way:

Let $n=2k$.

We show by strong induction that if $k \geq 2$ then there exists a graph with $2k$
vertices, all of which have degree 3.

P(2) is your pictures.

$P(2),P(3),.., P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$.

If $k=3$ this is your second picture. If $k \geq 4$ then $k-2 \geq 2$ and hence there exists a graph with $2k-4$ vertices, all of which have degree 3.

Take the union of this graph and $K_4$.